# mysql taking too much disk space in windows

Tags: mysql, memory-usage

I would like to know how MySQL uses disk space. Consider the following scenario.

1. I tried to import a large mysqldump (1.6 GB) using the command `mysql -u root dbname < mydump.sql`. But the import was failed and I got `table xxx is full` error.
2. I found that it was due to no memory left in C: drive. Actually, before importing the database, I had 4.1 GB free in C: drive. But after running the command, only 13 MB was left in C: drive.
3. To free up some space in C: drive, I dropped the database which I tried to import (as half of the total tables were imported already). But after deleting the database it freed up only 2 GB in C:drive now.

I have got a few questions here

1. Before importing I had 4.1 GB. After dropping the database I have 2.1 GB. So what is occupying the remaining 2GB data in my desk?
2. Is there a way I can find and clean that space? (I tried clearing `%temp%` system cache, and ran `FLUSH QUERY CACHE`. But nothing works)
3. If the mysqldump file is 1.96 GB, I thought the imported database will also be having almost the same size. If it is not, how much memory actually the database would occupy in the disk.

I managed to import the database after removing cache tables from the database. But I would like to know how to free up memory in my desk.

Comment: Do you have a data volume, independent of C:, with a few tens of GB of space? Single digit GB is not a lot of space to work with these days.

Comment: Unfortunately, No. This is my local development machine.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.10, for Win64 (x86_64)` Mysql 5.6